# Oboe for partial JSON?

Tags: oboe.js

In my use-case, I am continuously appending JSON objects to a file from an external application and then reading and parsing the JSON updates with NodeJS, which will send updates to the web browser for a D3 visualization.

The Oboe website is well done but I'm still not sure about the details of the file reading and JSON streaming to D3.  A live example of its use with D3 would be very helpful.

Is Oboe well-suited to this kind of task?  Are there any particular design patterns I should use?